# Why does Stackdriver logging does not respect the advanced filter condition for timestamp?

Tags: google-cloud-logging

I have selected 'No limit' then I wrote a simply filter in Logs Viewer console

```
timestamp>="2020-01-30T15:00:00Z" AND timestamp<="2020-01-30T16:00:00Z"
```

There is one log for this condition but it returned nothing in the console. When I changed the filter as follows,

```
timestamp>="2020-01-30T10:00:00Z" AND timestamp<="2020-01-30T16:00:00Z"
```

it shows me the result for `timestamp>="2020-01-30T15:00:00Z" AND timestamp<="2020-01-30T16:00:00Z"`.

And `timestamp>="2020-01-30T09:00:00Z" AND timestamp<="2020-01-30T16:00:00Z"` shows result for `timestamp>="2020-01-30T14:00:00Z" AND timestamp<="2020-01-30T16:00:00Z"`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For the base of my answer, I will be using this [**documentation**](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries) on advanced logs queries as the document shows you how to write advanced logs queries, which are the expressions that can specify a set of log entries from any number of logs.

To begin, the timestamp field type that you are using permits query value string in **RFC 3339** or **ISO 8601** format. In your case, you are using the **RFC 3339** type.

In query expressions, timestamps in **RFC 3339** format can specify a timezone with "**Z**" or **±hh:mm**. Also, timestamps are represented to nanosecond accuracy.

**More importantly**, when writing a query with a timestamp, you must also select **No limit** from the **time-range selector** below the search-query box. Check image below to have a visual.

[image: How to select No limit from the time-range selector]

So overall, there is nothing wrong with your query search:

```
timestamp>="2020-01-30T15:00:00Z" AND timestamp<="2020-01-30T16:00:00Z"
```

Just make sure that you have the **No limit** selected from the **time-range selector**.

If that still does not work for you, then you can try writing the same query search in a different format, like this:

```
timestamp >= "2020-01-30T15:00:00Z" timestamp <= "2020-01-30T16:00:00Z"
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I have select 'No limit' and used both my and your query in advanced query to test. It doesn't work. I have to give a period of 6 hours and the end time should be the originally intended end time to get logs between start time and end time for a period of 1 hour.

Comment: Hey again, sorry if the answer above didn't resolve your issue; This is very odd behavior coming from Stackdriver Logging. Maybe the issue could involve the timezone the log was created in. Try verify the log you are looking for, and see what timezone it was created in. Then try doing a custom search in the same timeslot plus the correct timezone. If you are still unable to retrieve the log(s) you are looking for, let me know.